# Проблема с вводом чисел с десятичной точкой в TextBox

Tags: c#, uwp

Приложение UWP. В манифесте проекта язык по умолчанию указан "ru-ru". В свойствах окна на XAML также прописано: Language="ru-ru". TextBox привязан к свойству, описанному в классе как double:

```
<TextBox Header="Курс евро" Margin="4" Text="{x:Bind SelectedExchangeRate.EUR, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    public class ExchangeRate
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }                   // Код записи
        public DateTimeOffset RateDate { get; set; }    // Дата курса валют
        public double EUR { get; set; }                 // Курс евро
    }
```

По кнопке "Сохранить" введенная запись добавляется в коллекцию.

При этом наблюдается следующая проблема. Если я ввожу данные в TextBox используя десятичную запятую, например 65,83 то в привязанный источник данных записывается целое число 65, а дробная часть числа отбрасывается. Если же я ввожу данные с использованием десятичной точки 65.83, то в источник данных сохраняется корректное число 65,83 но после обновления поля оно отображает уже не 65.83, а 65,83. Т. е. точка самопроизвольно заменяется на запятую. Соответственно, если после этого поле повторно получит фокус ввода и затем снова нажать кнопку "Сохранить" число опять потеряет дробную часть.
Понимаю, что проблема где-то в региональных настройках, но не могу понять где и что ещё сделать, чтобы ввод чисел с десятичной частью был корректен. Прошу подсказать как решить проблему.

Comment: Странно, в WPF воспроизвести не удалось. Вообще если стоит `Language="ru-ru"` то ввод числа с точкой приводит к ошибке валидации. UWP пока нету возможности проверить

Comment: А если заменить `x:Bind` на `Binding`?

Comment: В WPF такой проблемы не наблюдалось, проблема возникает именно в UWP. Менять на Binding не пробовал, проверю

Comment: Да, ещё выяснил что если в привязке x:Bind стоит режим привязки Mode=OneWay, то при указанных настройках числа с разделителем десятичной точкой игнорируются (сбрасываются в ноль), а числа с десятичной запятой корректно вводятся и сохраняются. Т. е. проблема возникает именно при Mode=TwoWay.

Comment: Ну а на Binding пробовали менять?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Нет, ещё не пробовал. Там весь код переписывать придется, x:Bind и Binding существенно различаются в привязке.

Comment: Так я вам не говорю все привязки менять, в одном месте попробуйте